# Convert XMLHttpRequest to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code and I want to convert in Jquery

```
function GetServerTime() 
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
   } else {  
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
   }

   xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax?type=GetServerTime&rand=" + Math.random(),false);
   xmlhttp.send();
   return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

can any one help??

Comment: You can't return from an asynchronous function, not even in jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Use [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax?type=GetServerTime&rand=" + Math.random(),
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  success: function(result) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax{
       url: "ajax?type=GetServerTime&rand=" + Math.random(),
       type: post,
       success: function(resp){
                 alert(resp);
                }
       }
```